# Visual studio - how to increase the size limit of the method helper box?

Tags: visual-studio

In visual studio when I start typing the values of a method a small helper box appears below the code and highlights in bold the name of the current parameter I am entering.

Now my problem is that I have a method that takes a ton of parameters, so much that they cannot fit in the helper box, and when I am entering the last parameters I have no clue which one I am entering since there are so many, and the bolded highlights really fix this issue.

Here is an image to illustrate the issue:
[image]

How can I make the box stretch past this limit?

Comment: I think if you have a method with that many parameters, you have a problem in code logic that goes well beyond trying to change Visual Studio..... You should seriously consider trying to simplify your code and research the Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: @Claies of course I can work around it, just wondering if there is a known easy fix for this. I dont see a reason why this box should have a size limit

Comment: fixing your code isn't a workaround;  any code that is workable without considerable risk of significant mistakes would never need more area for these tooltips.  You should actively consider code needing larger tooltips to be a code smell, telling you that your code is extremely too complex.

Comment: "fix" why? It's not broken, it doesn't impact performance, it's just a matter of hassle and quality of life(which would be solved by this box stretching rather than rewriting code)- but I get it that you want to push the issue strictly from an orthodox right way to code point of view

Comment: I mean, why not just let the box stretch until it's the only thing you can see?  Why not allow it to show 5000 arguments that are necessary to call a function rather than assume that having that many arguments is absurd and limit the size of the box?  The people who design these UI elements for Visual Studio have to make some assumptions about the expected use, for sanity of their code as much as yours.

Comment: for what it's worth, if your response to having a function with this many arguments to just be a "matter of hassle", I can't imagine the overall quality of this codebase.  This kind of "hassle" is a petri dish of impossible to troubleshoot errors and typos that turn a codebase into a spaghetti nightmare.

Comment: why get hung up on the quality of the codebase? Maybe its bad? I just wanted to know if there was an option to customize the box.